# Using param from relational database rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two controllers Businesses and Specials. They both have a tables one Business and one Special. They are relational. The controller Specials has a column called business_id which is connected to the database Business and that id. Im trying to make it so when you click on the link on the Specials controller index view the link to the business it goes to the Businesses controller show view so the link is Business/nameofbusiness

--- Businesses Controller ---

```
class BusinessesController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @business = Business.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

--- Business Model ---

```
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :specials
end
```

-- Specials Controller

```
class SpecialsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @specials = Special.all
    end
    def show
        @special = Special.find(params[:business])
    end
end
```

-- Special Model ---

```
class Special < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :business

end
```

--- Index View of Specials Controller --

```
<h1> Specials </h1>

<% @specials.each do |special| %>
<hr />
<h4> <%= link_to special.name, special %> </h1>
    <h6> <%= link_to special.business.business_name, business_path(@special) %> </h6>
    <p> <%= special.description %> </p>
<hr />

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to create a new route for that, since business_path will be converted to something like businesses/:id, so in your config/routes.rb you can add:

```
get "/businesses/:business_name" => "businesses#show", :as => :business_show
```

and of course on your controller you can't do a plain find anymore, so instead you can use something like this:

```
@business = Business.find_by_name(params[:business_name])
```

NOTE: here you would be having two routes with different params going to the same action (the business_path will continue to send requests with params[:id] to the show action) and there will be issues due to that, so you can do two things:

- If you're not going to use the default show route anymore (eg: businesses/:id), you can add this to your routes file:

  ```
  resources :businesses, except: :show
  ```
- Create a separate action for handling that kind of request, so instead of using show, use show_business for example.

  ```
   get "/businesses/:business_name" => "businesses#show_business", :as => :business_show
  ```

Comment: so no luck but i didn't get it working with the following  <h6> <%= link_to special.business.business_name, business_path(special.business.business_name) %> </h6>

Comment: If you used this approach: get "/businesses/:business_name" => "businesses#show", :as => :business_show you'll need to use business_show_path(special.business.business_name) and it should work (notice the name of the path is equal to the :as name you gave plus _path and passing in the parameter that in this case is the name)

Comment: i get unknown action it couldn't find the action show_business

Comment: That means in your route file you have get "/businesses/:business_name" => "businesses#show_business", :as => :business_show (I guess you decided to create a separate action to preserve the default business path as well), so you'll need to create a new action called show_business, here you perform the @business = Business.find_by_name(params[:business_name]) and render the 'show' page

Comment: I'm running rails 4 but I'm getting that find_by_name isn't a method

Comment: what is the name of the attribute? the syntax is the following: find_by_attribute_name (I was assuming the attribute name was 'name')

Comment: the attribute is business_name i tried that it didn't work @business = Business.find_business_name(params[:business_name])

Answer (score 0):

The link_to helper makes this super easy.  Use it this way.

```
<h6> <%= link_to special.business.business_name, special.business %> </h6>
```

If you want the name of the business in path you need to do more.  The gem [FriendlyId](http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/file.Guide.html) was made for this.  [Here's a great (free) railscast on how to use it.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid)

Comment: it gave me /businesses/1 because the id of 1 it should be the name

Comment: Are u sure? Because alwaya is the id

Comment: i got it to work <h6> <%= link_to special.business.business_name, special.business.business_name %> </h6> it worked but it is not a valid route